# Couchbase create document fails through sync-gateway public rest API

Tags: rest, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

As per Couchbase Sync-Gateway REST API documentation [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html#operation---db---put) below mentioned cURL should create a document in the specified database.

Below is the generated cURL from Postman.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 498d0fb6-77ac-9335-2379-14258c6731c7" -d '' "http://192.168.244.174:4984/db/"
```

I also tried adding JSON to the body of the request.

But when I send the put request through Postman, instead of creating a new document, it tries to create a new database and the JSON response is

```
{
 "error": "Precondition Failed",
 "reason": "Database already exists"
}
```

Am I missing something  or it was a bug? Is there any other way to create a document to sync gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the documentation.

As per documentation,

> You can either specify the document ID by including the _id object in the request message body, or let the software generate an ID.

But Couchbase REST API does not seem to work like that (may be they are not updating their documentation regularly). You need to provide the id in the URL like `/{db}/{id}`.

The below cURL worked for me.

`curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 75ab844e-5130-708e-69e9-e87f878108b4" -d '{"name": "xxx",
"full_name": "xxx yyy"}' "http://192.168.244.174:4984/db/123"`

JSON response is

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "ok": true,
  "rev": "1-9324dabc947fc963a754b113d1215ac3"
}
```